# numpy stack rows of ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I have a ndarray A of shape (u,v,w) like this:

```
  [[[ 1.,  1.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  3.,  0.]],

   [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]]
```

I need to stack the rows (along dimension 0) together like so.

```
[[1.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
 [1.,   3.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]]
```

How do I do this?
I know that if there are only two rows I can do np.hstack((a[0], a[1])) but is there any way to do this without converting the rows into a tuple? I want to use this code in theano (because numpy and theano work similarly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shoul work fine:

```
np.hstack(a)
```

Btw `a[0], a[1], ...` are the rows and not columns of `a`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would do this with a tensor3 variable in theano?

Comment: Look into `T.reshape` and `T.dimshuffle`. The combination of both should allow you to do pretty much anything you like.

Comment: T.stack doesn't do it if you pass in a single tensor. You have to pass in a list of tensors

Comment: I was able to do it using dimshuffle and repeat. It's T.dimshuffle(1,0,2).reshape((v,-1))

Answer (score 4):

All the `concatenate` family of functions iterate over the argument, whether it's a list, tuple or array

```
In [318]: x=np.arange(12).reshape(2,2,3)

In [319]: x
Out[319]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])
```

These all equivalent:

```
In [320]: np.hstack([x[0],x[1]])
Out[320]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  9, 10, 11]])

In [321]: np.hstack(x)
Out[321]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  9, 10, 11]])

In [322]: np.concatenate([x1 for x1 in x],axis=1)
Out[322]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  9, 10, 11]])

In [323]: np.concatenate(x,axis=1)
Out[323]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Reshape can produce an array of the right shape, but the wrong order:

```
In [332]: x.reshape(2,6)
Out[332]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

but if we swap the 1st 2 axes first, reshape works:

```
In [333]: x.transpose(1,0,2).reshape(2,6)
Out[333]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Comment: Should I accept the first answer or the more complete one?

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would do this with a tensor3 variable in theano?

Comment: Sorry, I've ignored Theano.